# PostgreSQL Race condition and Serializable

Tags: postgresql, transaction, serialization

Hello I try to debug a tricky race condition in my app (golang, pq, sqlx, postgresql Debian 10.6-1.pgdg90+1).

I have a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE j (
  id              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY        NOT NULL,
  "type"          VARCHAR(10)                  NOT NULL,
  complete        BOOLEAN        DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
  started_at      TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
                                 DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  error           TEXT           DEFAULT ''    NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX jtype ON j("type");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX jtype_one_active ON j("type") WHERE complete = false;
```

to track some jobs

The job is created with `complete=false`, and later updated to `complete=true`. Errors are logged, so there are multiple rows per "type", but only one job should be active.

First, with a naive approach, I did that:

```sql
SELECT j.*
            FROM j
            WHERE "type" = ...
            ORDER BY started_at DESC
            LIMIT 1


-- some in app business logic

INSERT INTO j ("type")
            VALUES ($1)
        RETURNING *
```

It worked ok, but running parallel test I found a race condition on empty table:

- Process A: SELECT ...
- Process B: SELECT ... (both select no rows)
- Process A: INSERT / UPDATE (process A inserts a new row AND proceeds to update it to `complete=true`, so `jtype_one_active` index won't fire)
- Process B: INSERT ...

So the job is running twice, even if process A completes with no error.

I wrapped CREATE + INSERT into a single Serializable transaction (also, added `FOR UPDATE` to CREATE. And it worked for the most part.

**The real question starts here**:

But when I added more concurrency to my test I found, that sometimes the job is still running twice.

Here's what I managed to debug, but it might not be 100% true:

The table is empty

- Process A: begins transaction
- Process A: SELECT (no rows)
- Process A: CREATE
- Process B: begins transaction
- Process B: runs SELECT **and select is running slow due high concurrency**
- Process A: commits transaction
- Process B: SELECT completes, no rows is found
- Process B: INSERT (no serialisable error is fired!!)
- Process B: commits transaction (no error is fired!!)

Does a long running SELECT FOR UPDATE query somehow "escapes" Serializable Isolation? Or there's another flow in my script?

**Update**

I've managed to get the same behaviour on just 2 parallel processes and record a PostgreSQL log: https://pastebin.com/HgzwC9Wh

Log looks close to my previous guess, though I'm not sure, if `SELECT` in process B really takes a lot of time.

For some reason, after the A transaction commits, the B `SELECT` doesn't see committed data! It returns no rows.

I tried to replay this from psql shell with no success.

Comment: The only logical explanation would be that the two transactions use using different `type`s, so that they don't interfere with each other. Can you provide a repeatable test case with complete statements? Also, I don't understand the logic of your table. Why is the race condition a problem for you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug that from the postgres side. And it breaks business logic (completed job should not be restarted, no parallel jobs of same type)

Comment: You can turn on statement logging. I still think that cannot happen unless the `type`s differ.

Comment: I recorded a PostgreSQL log. `type`s are the same. Now, the second transaction makes `SELECT` 5ms after the first transaction committed, but it looks like, it sees no committed data. Weird

Comment: are you sure that there are two active rows with the same type, exact steps to replicate this would be useful.

Comment: _For some reason, after the A transaction commits, the B SELECT doesn't see committed data! It returns no rows_: that's the expected behavior under the serializable isolation level. _Process A: CREATE_: create what?

Comment: @DanielVérité If the `SELECT` is the first statement in the serializable transaction, it should see changes previously committed. We really need to know the statements and their exact sequence to debug this.